# How to create seperate div from result fetch from database in php

Tags: php, html

I'm working at brainstorming app, where participants provide their ideas on specific topic, using js to feature drag the received ideas inside the screen. But results fetched from database acts as single entity and cannot be drag as separate div. Where do i need to change to fetched results as separate div entity to move individual styled data around screen?

Php, sql, phpmyadmin

```php
// sql 
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM brainstrom WHERE bstopic_ref=:ref ORDER BY created_at';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql2);
$statement->execute([':ref' => $ref]);
$bs = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Draggable JS library used: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Code to generate divs:

```php
<div id = "mydiv" style = "width:300px;  padding: 0 15px; background: aquamarine; border-top:5px solid #fff;">
<?php foreach ($bs as $a) :?>
    <div id="mydivheader" class="row" style="padding: 0 15px 10px;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <?php echo $a->priority; ?> |
            <?php echo $a->bscategory_ref; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;">
            <a href="edit_bs.php?ref=<?php echo $a->ref ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 20px;"> </i> </a>
            <a onclick="return confirm('Are your sure to delete ?')" href="del_bs.php?ref=<?php echo $a->ref ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $a->point; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <small><?php echo $a->created_by; ?> at <?php echo $a->created_at; ?></small>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<!-- /.mydiv -->
```

Expected output:
Drag-able separate fetch results from database.

Comment: Hi problem with id id="mydivheader" in loop its creating same div with same id, id should be unique not be same. you can give name with foreach loop key like foreach ($bs as $key => $a) so id will be id="mydivheader<?php echo $key; ?>"

Comment: Thanks @NileshDaldra , id issue got solved but still can't move as separate div, all fetched data moves at once. Could you please help more to separate as individual row..